# Ubuntu Server - After reboot key always refused, until login

Tags: server, ssh

I installed Ubuntu Server and also configured the ssh server. I tried the "key system", so I have a public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and also configured this file in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

When I manually (locally, via the keyboard connected to the server) login on the server PC I can remotely connect via ssh with the private key to the server. However if I reboot the server, and I do not login locally first, and I try to connect via ssh I always get the error:

```
Server refused our key
```

However if I then again login locally login, I can again connect via ssh using the keys.

What might I be doing wrong?

(BTW I rebooted using `sudo reboot`)

Comment: Is your user's home directory i.e. the location of (`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`) encrypted?

Comment: Yes it is, could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes - see [SSH pubkey authentication works only if another session is already open](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32725/ssh-pubkey-authentication-works-only-if-another-session-is-already-open)

Comment: That is what I noticed indeed. Is there a way to get around? If I want to reboot my server remotely for example

Comment: The [answer to the question I linked](http://askubuntu.com/a/32788/178692) explains the recommended way around it - put your user's authorized_keys file somewhere that isn't encrypted, such as /etc/ssh/<user>/, and modify the configuration file accordingly

Comment: Yes that is indeed the solution, I just figured it out at the same moment. Thanks for the support!